# In Typescript, Returns typed value depends on key from Object that provided thru arguments

Tags: typescript

I tried like below to returns various types depends on input string key, but it doesn't works.

How to make the `getSpecificData` functions to return type I want?

```
type Data = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;
};

function getSpecificData<D>(data: D, dataKey: keyof D): D[keyof D] {
  return data[dataKey];
}

const sampleData: Data = {
  foo: 'hello',
  bar: 123,
  baz: false,
};

const foo: string = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'foo'); // the function returns string|number|boolean
const bar: number = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'bar');
const baz: boolean = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'baz');
```

[Link to Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBmB7PALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbiygCM5zjqBXAW2YnMbZWAL2LMCAGwhxqjAL6MMOTtQDGwSnmpRaEYAGVIqyjkqr4iADwwAfAAoAJgjjEYAGihPEAaQghiANZ+eDiwAJSuANpBICGwALroTOR6nOTaXnCRmb4g8fIYGKpaZKRw3GBSFi6wzihJ2PhEUADkABYQEhJ4LW5MrOxQAIwATADMfUJworhwEiQQfQqFxdSlTcRkVHT1ugZGJmbVdiTllRDVHi1NLWGMq6UDHDx85Lt6hhDGpubOJ2dVZxXAa3e4lYAsaZiSTSbSoPafb5HP6nCqAxDA6agjBAA)

Comment: The key needs to be generic.  I know there are loads of similar questions about this.

Comment: `function getSpecificData<D, K extends keyof D>(data: D, dataKey: K): D[K] {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the key and the value need to be generic in order to get the value type for the specific key that you provided.  `D[keyof D]` is a union of all possible value types, but `D[K]` will give us the correct value for a given key `K`.

```
function getSpecificData<D, K extends keyof D>(data: D, dataKey: K): D[K] {
  return data[dataKey];
}
```

This allows Typescript to return the specific value type associated with the provided key.  Now all of these examples work:

```
const foo: string = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'foo');
const bar: number = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'bar');
const baz: boolean = getSpecificData(sampleData, 'baz');
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mMy4Zm)